# Communication Between Components and Injectables in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm looking for a 'best-practice' type suggestion when dealing with component and service communication in ng2.

Let's say, for example, I have the following:

```
//auth.service.ts
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    login() {
       //do some login stuff here
    }

}

//login.component.ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AuthService} from './path/to/auth.service';

@Component({

    selector: 'app-login',
    template: '<button (click)="">Login</button>',
    providers: [AuthService]

})

export class LoginComponent {

    constructor (
    public _authService: AuthService
    ) {}

}
```

My question is mainly centered around this:

```
<button (click)="">Login</button>
```

Should I just do something like `(click)="_authService.login()"` or, should I create a login method inside of the LoginComponent and reference that in the view?

```
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>

export class LoginComponent {

    constructor (
    public _authService: AuthService
    ) {}

    login() {
    this._authService.login();
    }

}
```

I'm thinking the latter since it feels like the view is then completely decoupled from the service, however, I've seen comments where people prefer the initial approach. Furthermore, there's cases where `_authService` might also have some data that needs to be bound to the view in which case, the only way the view can detect changes to that data is by binding directly to `_authService`.

Which approach is considered a best practice when creating communication between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to have the service be private and use a method in your component to call the service. Usually the underscore in the variable name means that it was meant to be private.

```
constructor (
    private _authService: AuthService
    ) {}
```

This keeps your code more modular. If you decide to use a difference service or write your own logic to do the same thing, you won't have to go update the HTML in the template. You just update your method.